# Why does PHP function need to be before call when using if !defined

Tags: php, defined

In the following example code the call to the function o_h_loaded is before the function itself. This produces Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function o_h_loaded().

```
<?php 
if ( !defined( "O_H" ) ) {
define( "O_H", "O_H" );

o_h_loaded();

function o_h_loaded() {
    echo "o_h_loaded";
}

} /* end if */
```

If I do either of the following it works

1. Move the call to after the function
2. Comment out the if !defined test

I'd love to know why.

Comment: move out your function to outside of `if` you can also you `if function_exists('o_h_loaded')`

Comment: What's your confusion - you can't drive the car until you've bought the car. So it's trying to use the function before it is declared. This has nothing to do with your `defined` call which is for completely different variables/data.

Comment: PHP evaulates code in execution order - it's doesn't parse the file, evaulate it, and then run the code.

Comment: @Martin we can call a function and define it later in script.

Comment: @Martin It has everything to do with the `if` block. As expressly mentioned in the question, if the `if` block it omitted, the code runs, despite the function call appearing before the function definition

Comment: @bobbingwide if we defined method into within control structure (If) then it flow line by line other wise it load whole code and check if there is any function exist in script.

Comment: The use of a constant which is NOT the function name is intentional. The whole purpose of using the constant was to avoid having to wrap each function in a !function_exists() check. This is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

First off, PHP parses the file to look for common errors and sets up the symbols. Since I am no authority on this, *I believe* PHP does a first-level check for symbols and a deeper level check for syntax compliance.

With this premise, if you remove the `if` statement, all code becomes first level. The function call would work because the function symbol would be registered. This is also the case when you move the function declaration before the function call with the `if` statement still there.

You can wrap the function call in a `function_exists` check, if you must absolutely have the call before the declaration.

Comment: Hi @yasky, thanks for your answer. The PHP interpreter certainly has some interesting logic with regards to parsing the source and building its symbol tables.

It seems odd that commenting out or moving lines of code around can produce such different results. 

Wrapping the function call in a function_exists() test defeats the purpose of the code. I do want the function to be invoked and I do want the !defined test, so the call will have to be after the definition.

Comment: Yeah, it sure does. When I find more concrete information on this, I shall update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define what the function is ***before*** you call it and try and use it.

Also your `defined` query is asking if a CONSTANT has been defined rather than the *function*.

Here is a working edit of your code:

```
<?php 
//declare what the function is at the start of the page
function o_h_loaded() {
    echo "o_h_loaded";
}

if ( !defined( "O_H" ) ) { // This call has nothing to do with 
define( "O_H", "O_H" );    // The function declared above.

// Now call to the function declared already. Hence resolving the fatal error. 
o_h_loaded();

} /* end if */
```

---

To answer your question - the reason it works this way is that PHP reads the file from top to bottom, left to right. And because it's not a class file the data and syntax is processed only in the order it is recieved.

Comment: But this is conflicting in a sense though. If you look at the code, the `o_h_loaded` function should only be declared if the `O_H` constant is. I know there's not much changes in runtime behaviour if this function never gets called. But this changes the design entirely.

Comment: This has never proved to be a problem for me in the past. But just to make doubly sure I ran a test on 5.1 and 5.3, in both cases, calling the function before it is declared worked as expected.

Comment: I didn't define fully the purpose of the if !defined on the constant. 

It's to cater for multiple instances of the code being loaded in different files, and I don't want to wrap each function in a function_exists() test. So the constant is defined at the file level. 

The invocation of the function o_h_loaded() is required, but only once.

e.g. <?php require("o-h".php"); 
require( "o-h.php" );

should only produce "o_h_loaded" once